# How to match only letters from a string containing alphanumeric and symbols?

Tags: regex

log : Description: "AMEND - 04 ACCEPTED"
Output: AMEND ACCEPTED

I have tried to write regex as Description:\s"([A-Z]+)". but its matching only 1st word.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your tool or language, a regex find all might make the most sense here.  You may match on the pattern `\b[A-Z]+\b`.

[Here is a demo](https://regex101.com/delete/d72ITQo4eWkqf60GbLqdAxXy).

In Python, we can try:

```py
inp = "AMEND - 04 ACCEPTED"
matches = re.findall(r'\b[A-Z]+\b')
print(matches)  # ['AMEND', 'ACCEPTED']
```

Comment: \b[A-Z]+b is matching only AMEND not AMEND ACCEPTED

Comment: What is your language or tool?

Comment: SIEM Qradar tool

Comment: I don't know the tool, but to get the exact output you want you'll need some kind of regex replacement operation.